# how do i change hyperlinks inside pdf using python?

Tags: python, pdf, hyperlink

How do I change the hyperlinks in pdf using python? I am currently using a pyPDF2 to open up and loop through the pages. How do I actually scan for hyperlinks and then proceed to change the hyperlinks?

Answer (score 8):

So I couldn't get what you want using the [pyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) library.

I did however get something working with another library: [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw). This installed fine for me using pip in Python 3.6:

```
pip install pdfrw
```

*Note: for the following I have been using [this example pdf](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) I found online which contains multiple links. Your mileage may vary with this.*

```
import pdfrw

pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader("pdf.pdf")  # Load the pdf
new_pdf = pdfrw.PdfWriter()  # Create an empty pdf

for page in pdf.pages:  # Go through the pages

    # Links are in Annots, but some pages don't have links so Annots returns None
    for annot in page.Annots or []:

        old_url = annot.A.URI

        # >Here you put logic for replacing the URLs<
        
        # Use the PdfString object to do the encoding for us
        # Note the brackets around the URL here
        new_url = pdfrw.objects.pdfstring.PdfString("(http://www.google.com)")

        # Override the URL with ours
        annot.A.URI = new_url

    new_pdf.addpage(page)    

new_pdf.write("new.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2).

If you just want to remove all annotations for a page, you just have to do:

```py
if '/Annots' in page: del page['/Annots']
```

Else, here is how you change each link:

```py
import PyPDF2

new_link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" # great video by the way

pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("input.pdf")
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
    
    if '/Annots' not in page: continue
    for annot in page['/Annots']:
        annot_obj = annot.getObject()
        if '/A' not in annot_obj: continue  # not a link
        # you have to wrap the key and value with a TextStringObject:
        key   = PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject("/URI")
        value = PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject(new_link)
        annot_obj['/A'][key] = value
    
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)

with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    pdf_writer.write(f)
```

An equivalent one-liner for a given page index `i` and annotation index `j` would be:

```py
pdf_reader.getPage(i)['/Annots'][j].getObject()['/A'][PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject("/URI")] = PyPDF2.generic.TextStringObject(new_link)
```

Comment: how to open that URL in a new tab, currently it is opening in the same window when opened in browser.